# Finding the best fit parameters for only a certain segment of data

Tags: curve-fitting, nonparametric

I have some experimental data that are observations of an $n$ dimensional quantity, $x = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$. I also have a complicated parameterized model $f(a,b)$ for the data, which for a given choice of $a$ and $b$, will spit out an $n$ dimensional vector $y = \{y_1, y_2, \ldots,y_n\}$. $y$ is supposed to be "similar" to $x$ for certain segment with indices $1< i, i+1,\ldots,j<n$ ($i$ and $j$ are known). The objective is to find the $a$ and $b$ that best describes $x$ (more on how after the list).

Since my actual application is complicated and time consuming I won't be able to share the data, but I'll mention some specifics and provide sample data:

- I don't have an analytic form for $f$; it's a complex numerical simulation that just spits out the list given $a$ and $b$.
- The underlying distribution for $x$ is not known.
- All $x_i$ and $y_i$ are non-negative

Here's some sample data (*Mathematica* code, but feel free to use any language you like):

```
test = Sort@RandomReal[ChiSquareDistribution[1], {1000}];
f[a_, b_] := a Sort@RandomReal[ChiSquareDistribution[b], {1000}]^2;
```

Now if we look at the plots of the test data and the model for some values of `a` and `b` that I eyeballed to look good:

```
ListLinePlot[Log10@{test, f[0.064, 3.3]}]
```

[image: Image 1]

you see what I mean by "similar" for a certain segment (here indices between 300 to 900). Compare this with an arbitrary choice of `a` and `b` that are "not similar"

```
ListLinePlot[Log10@{test, f[0.4, 1.3]}]
```

[image: Image 2]

Assuming that this similarity segment 300 – 900 is known, how would I select the right values for a and b?

My idea was to discretize the space spanned by `a` and `b` (sensible values for both are known *a priori*, and for the above, if necessary, you can pick $a\in[0.05, 1], b\in[2.5,4]$) and try to find the combination that would minimize $\Vert \{x_i,\ldots,x_j\} - \{y_i,\ldots,y_j\}\Vert_p$, where $p$ is either 1 or 2 depending on how I want to weight the outliers. Trying this out,

```
res = With[{t = Take[test, {300, 900}]}, 
    Table[Norm[t - Take[f[a, b], {300, 900}], 2], 
        {a, 0.5, 1, 0.01}, {b, 2.5, 4, 0.01}]];
```

unfortunately gives something like this

[image: Image 3]

which does not indicate a clear minimum. Similar result for the $L_1$ norm as well... I also tried taking the $\log_{10}$ of each and then finding the error (is that even valid?), but that wasn't helpful either.

I've seem to have hit a wall on finding a way to identify the right (or close to the right) parameters. Would it be possible to, instead, use the slope and curvature of the segment to find the parameters instead of a point-by-point error?

I'd appreciate any pointers towards a possible solution. I can do the programming myself, and can understand logic in most common programming languages, so that's not a barrier.

> **NOTE:** My data is *not* $\chi^2$ distributed, nor is the model. This is just an example that I picked, since I could illustrate how the shape is the same in the segment, but not elsewhere.